# Is this Juno CDT eclipse.ini file correct?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I recently changed my `eclipse.ini` file for Eclipse Juno CDT. Eclipse then started going into a 'Not responding' mode for several seconds, especially after builds and searches. Lots of disk activity.

I think I put the `eclipse.ini` file back to valid values.

Does the `eclipse.ini` have reasonable, consistent values?

The 'Not responding' problem may be elsewhere, but I want to make sure my Eclipse configuration is not the problem.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine as long as you're using it for the c++ product, not the Java one.

This is denoted by

`org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product`

Everything else you have is very similar to mine.  Pasted mine below for your reference (I'm using the Java EE version)...

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2560m
```

Comment: Your ini file does not have <code>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</code> and you -Xms and -Xmx are much larger. I've made the changes and the 'Not responding' is less, but not gone.